# return from jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, return-value

I'm trying to use the return from a jQuery ajax call in my own function, but it keeps returning undefined.

```
function checkUser2(asdf) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "check_user.php",
        data: { name: asdf },
        success: function(data){ 
            return data;
            //alert(data);
        }
    });  
}

$("#check").click(function(){
    alert(checkUser2("muma"));
});
```

the ajax call definitely works, because when I uncomment my alert I get the correct return, and I can see it in firebug. Am I doing something stupid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The AJAX call is asynchronous - this means that the AJAX request is made out-of-order of usual program execution, and in your program that means that `checkUser2()` is not returning data to the alert.

You cannot use return values from `$.ajax()` calls in this way, instead move the code that utilises the AJAX return data to the `success()` function - that what it's for.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this, I think:

```
function checkUser2(asdf) {
  var s = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "check_user.php",
        data: { name: asdf },
        success: function(data){ 
            return data;
            //alert(data);
        }
    }).responseText;  
   return s;
}
```

but, as in the 4th example of the [jquery doc page for ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) says, I think that

> Blocks the browser while the requests is active. It is better to block user interaction > by other means when synchronization is necessary.

Comment: This fixes the problem I had in almost the exact same scenario, as the "async: false" was the key part to stop the call being made asyncronously.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
 function checkUser2(asdf) {
    var result;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: "check_user.php",
        data: { name: asdf },
        success: function(data){ 
            result = data;            
        }
    });
    return result;  
}       


$("#check").click(function(){
    alert(checkUser2("muma"));
});
```

You may have to move the result variable out as a global javascript variable instead. I haven't tested this yet.

Comment: Synchronous ajax is a really bad idea however.

Comment: I agree, but it was a way around the problem the OP had. And he was already using the ajax function in an asynchronous way.

Comment: This way didn't work for me either.         $("#submitPO").click(function(){
             alert(updatePO("444"));            
        }); failed to pop an alert. My function is structured in the same way as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You could also store the "data" using jQuery's data method and associate it with a global jQuery object or local jQuery selector. For e.g.

```
success: function(data) {
  $.data('result', data);
}
```

The return value can the be accessed anywhere using

```
$.data('result')
```

You could also associate this to a local variable (for e.g. $('#myid').data()) so that its local to that object rather than in the global scope.

Comment: I tried using your suggestion. I couldn't get it to work.         $("#submitPO").click(function(){
             alert($.data('result'));            
        }); did nothing.